# Test class not working for more than two or three methods in same class it fails for other two methods only one method covers

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, code-coverage

```
public with sharing class TransactionsalSecurity {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ReportEvent> TransactionalSecurityToday()
    {
        return [SELECT Name, QueriedEntities, Format, EventSource, NumberOfColumns, Operation, EventIdentifier, PolicyOutcome, Username, EventDate FROM ReportEvent WHERE EventDate = Today];
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ReportEvent> TransactionalSecurityYesterday()
    {
        return [SELECT Name, QueriedEntities, Format, EventSource, NumberOfColumns, Operation, EventIdentifier, PolicyOutcome, Username, EventDate FROM ReportEvent WHERE EventDate = Yesterday];
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ReportEvent> TransactionalSecurityTweek()
    {
        return [SELECT Name, QueriedEntities, Format, EventSource, NumberOfColumns, Operation, EventIdentifier, PolicyOutcome, Username, EventDate FROM ReportEvent WHERE EventDate = THIS_WEEK];
     }
}
```

My test Class

```
public class TransactionalSecurityTest {
    @isTest
    static void TransactionalSecurityTest()
    {
        test.startTest();

        List<ReportEvent> a= TransactionsalSecurity.TransactionalSecurityYesterday();
        List<ReportEvent> b= TransactionsalSecurity.TransactionalSecurityToday();
        List<ReportEvent> x= TransactionsalSecurity.TransactionalSecurityTweek();
        test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what your issue is. Please [edit] your question to use more words to describe your problem. You're also not creating any test data, or making any assertions. Going through some of the [tag:canonical-qa] tagged questions may be beneficial.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't cover all methods

Comment: it covers only first method of my apex class rest methods are not covered

Answer (score 0):

Actually the motive of test class is not to cover your functionality.
Use of Test class.

1. The test class is generally used to test your actual functionality.
2. the test class is checking Expected results with Actual results.
3. Please check this module to explore more about test class [Test class Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro)

---

Now come to your problem.

1. You do not create any test data in your test class.
2. Please create test data using @testSetup [testSetupMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm).
3. Test class Code should look like.
4. ```
   @isTest
   private class TestClass {
   @testSetup static void setup() {
       // Create test records which are you using in your actual class.          
   }

   @isTest
   static void TransactionalSecurityTest()
   {
       test.startTest();
       List<ReportEvent> a= TransactionsalSecurity.TransactionalSecurityYesterday();
       //To do - check actual vs expected results for List a, using System.assert
       List<ReportEvent> b= TransactionsalSecurity.TransactionalSecurityToday();
       //To do - check actual vs expected results for List b, using System.assert
       List<ReportEvent> x= TransactionsalSecurity.TransactionalSecurityTweek();
       //To do - check actual vs expected results for List b, using System.assert
       test.stopTest();
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: the problem is not that simple the test class is for bigobject report event which is failing we are able to execute same test class for normal object without passing any value